# volley not populating ListView with remote server

Tags: php, android, json, listview, android-volley

My android app connects with a server and get information from a database and fills in a listview. it works fine with **xampp** on my *localhost*. but after uploading my files to my server it doesn't work. no error in the log except.

> D/Volley: [1] 2.onErrorResponse: ViewGuidesActivity

But when i run my **PHP** file on my web browser it returns the **JSON** data perfectly.

```
public class ViewGuidesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = ViewGuidesActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Guide> guideList = new ArrayList<Guide>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_guides);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, guideList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(AppConfig.URL_GET_GUIDE_LIST,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Guide guide = new Guide();
                            guide.setNgno(obj.getString("ngno"));
                            guide.setEmail(obj.getString("email"));
                            guide.setName(obj.getString("name"));


                            // adding movie to movies array
                            guideList.add(guide);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
            Guide newGuide = guideList.get(position);
            String email = newGuide.getEmail();
            String ngno = newGuide.getNgno();
            //System.out.println(email);

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GuideDetails.class);
            i.putExtra("email", email);
            i.putExtra("ngno", ngno);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
```

**My php file:**

```
$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql = "select * from guide"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
         while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
              $json[]=$row;
         }
}
mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($json);
```

I'm aware that i'm using some deprecated methods, because i refereed to an outdated tutorial, and im in the process of converting all the **PHP** files to use **mysqli**. But first i needed to get my app working.

Here is my **JSON** data:

http://srilankatouristguides.com/guideList.php

I'm using the same URL in my code. What could be the issue? cant figure it out since it works fine with my *localhost*. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check whether db username,password and host is correct or not

Comment: 1.Check if onResponse method returns expected result. 2) Maybe post adapter code.

Comment: Please show us what the line `Log.d(TAG, response.toString());` is printing - or that it gets printed at all. We need to confirm whether this is the question of data not being returned from server or the listview not updating.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. Not using **mysqli** was causing connectivity issues. Probably the server is not using the deprecated methods so my code did not work. After converting my **PHP** code to **mysqli**, everything works. Thanks for the pointers guys!